# spring-authorization-server What is a good clustering solution

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-authorization-server

I used springcloud to build a spring-authorization-server, which has 2 themall-oauth2-server clusters (spring-authorization-server), and then themall-system (this is resource.) Now if theymall-system and themall-oauth2- The server has built two services (a total of 4 servers), which will cause some problems. When I enter themall-system from the gateway, and then redirect to themall-oauth2-server, it may go to a different node. Then log in again. When logging in again, the user and menu will be queried. There may be use success, and sometimes menu success. Does anyone have any good solutions, or where should I go to find the answer? I'm not sure if this description is clear enough. If there are any problems, please contact me to correct it.

If I change spring-authorization-server to a server. (replicas: 1), this problem can be solved. What should I do if it is a cluster